# Try to find sum between 2 csv columns - Python

Tags: python, csv, sum

I have a csv file and i am trying to find the sum between 2 columns. the csv file looks like this [image: csv file]

I want to find the difference between row[2] and row[3] for each row and after that to add it in a sum. My code looks like that:

```
senti_results = 0
concept_results = 0


for row in inputTweets:
    senti_results = senti_results + float((row[2]) - (row[3]))
    concept_results = concept_results + float((row[2]) -(row[5]))
```

But i have the following error

```
File "C:/Users/nelli_000/PycharmProjects/finaltest/results.py", line 15, in <module>
    senti_results = senti_results + float((row[2]) - (row[3]))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

can anyone help me? thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You a trying to subtract two strings and then convert the result to a float. Try adding `float` around each row access instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to subtract two strings and then cast that as a float, try casting the strings as floats first. Like so:

change

```
float((row[2])-(row[3]))
```

to

```
float(row[2])-float(row[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas.

```
import pandas
csvfile = pandas.read_csv('path/to/csv/file')
result = csvfile['row_x'] + csvfile['row_y']
```

where **row_x** and **row_y** are the headers of the columns you want to sum. You might have to set the data type with the **dtype** parameter in pandas.read_csv().

Source: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

You have missed float function for row[3] & row[5]

```
senti_results = 0
concept_results = 0


for row in inputTweets:
    senti_results = senti_results + float((row[2]) - float(row[3]))
    concept_results = concept_results + float((row[2]) -float(row[5]))
```